# How can I determine a process' unshared memory size on SunOS?

Tags: apache, memory, process, solaris, mod-perl

Is there a way to determine the unshared memory size of a process on SunOS? Specifically the size of a child httpd process running under mod_perl if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try *pmap -x* - see [Solaris Internals: Process Memory Map: pmap -x](http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/Processes#Process_Memory_Map:_pmap_-x) for an example and details.

Comment: Do you know if this reads the file from /proc? I'm preferably looking for a solution that calls a C lib.